# TikZ PGF: How to draw crater-like 3D surface based on polynomial equations?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Assumed we have some kind of squared 3D graph like this one:

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples=20]
      \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2] {-x^2-y^2};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Visualization of pipe flow]

---

How can I replace the current graph with some 4th degree polynomial formula in both directions `x` and `y`, e.g. `-1/3*x^4+x^2` and `-1/3*y^4+y^2`?

---

**Draft of the desired result**

In the end it should look like that:

[image: Draft of the desired result]

The draft is more or less a circular volcano with a crater in the middle, I hope you can imagine. :-)

I don't know why, but several approaches with...

```
\addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2] {(-1/3*y^4+y^2)*(-1/3*y^4+y^2)};
```

... do not show up like I expected.

Comment: Have you tried replacing two of the `y` in your formula with `x`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something of this sort? (Up to a sign this is a so-called Mexican hat potential.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples=20,zmin=0,zmax=1]
      \addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,z buffer=sort]
       ({x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)},{3*(0.5*x^2-x^4)+0.5});
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you do

```
 \addplot3[surf, domain=-1:1] {(x^2+y^2)-0.5*(x^2+y^2)^2};
```

you'll get

[image]

Yes, it is possible to extend the plot to the axes, but it is not as straightforward as one may think (or I am missing something obvious).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x^2+\y^2)-0.5*(\x^2+\y^2)^2;}]
   \begin{axis}[samples=20,zmin=0,zmax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
    % \clip (-1,-1,{f(-1,-1)}) -- (1,-1,{f(1,-1)}) -- (1,1,{f(1,1)})
    % --  (1,1,1) -- (-1,-1,1); % not needed
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2,samples=50,point meta={max(f(x,y),0)}] {f(x,y)};   
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One way to obtain a more shallow local minimum is to increase the plot range.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=(\x^2+\y^2)-0.5*(\x^2+\y^2)^2;}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxmax}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myzmin}{f(\myxmax,0)}
   \begin{axis}[samples=20,zmin=\myzmin,zmax=1,xmin=-\myxmax,xmax=\myxmax,ymin=-\myxmax,ymax=\myxmax]
    \addplot3[surf, domain=-2:2,samples=50,point meta={max(f(x,y),\myzmin)}] {f(x,y)};   
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help! Your second picture looks beautiful! Would it be possible to let the graph end at the line of each bottom edge? And maybe the the "crater" in the middle not that deep? Half depth would be enough... :-)

Comment: @Dave I added a proposal for that.

Comment: @Dave I added a way to get a more shallow minimum. This way is not unique.

Comment: I guess you can probably help me along with a further question as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473081/tikz-pgf-how-to-style-parts-of-3d-graph-lower-than-surface-as-invisible